# () Operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++11

This question has been asked before but not answered satisfactorily.

I have a class which is acting as an event handler and I would like to have a nice syntax for calling the event handler outside of an event. What this boils down to is overriding the () operator. I currently have

```
class EventHandler
{
public:
    void Call(void* sender, EventArgs e);

    void operator() (void* sender, EventArg e){ Call(sender, e); }
};
```

which works fine. I can call the event handler via

```
EventHandler EH;
EH(nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());
```

My problem lies in that I usually store the event handler on the heap so I need

```
EventHandler* EH;
EH(nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());  // error but this is the syntax I'm hoping for
```

but this can only be done with

```
EventHandler* EH;
(*EH)(nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());  // no error
```

How can I override the () operator to have it work with the pointer to the EventHandler object? I have seen some things that look like overloading the ->() operator instead of just the () operator but I haven't been able to make sense of it.

Comment: Maybe the reason a satisfactory answer doesn't exist is because it isn't possible? The compiler recognizes a pointer to a function and allows you to drop the dereference, but there's no corresponding shortcut for pointers to class objects.

Comment: You can turn a non-null pointer into a reference to get the syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator `->()` doesn't exists.

There are two ways to call the operator.

```
EventHandler* EH;
(*EH)(nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());
```

or

```
EventHandler* EH;
EH->operator()(nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());
```

This works in the same way as the `operator=` or any other operator

Answer (score 2):

"My problem lies in that I usually store the event handler on the heap so I need"

Is there a reason for this? If the EH involves a large amount of state, then perhaps you could build a wrapper class that put the state on the heap but that itself was allocated as an object. This would allow overloading `operator()()` and getting the desired syntax, while forwarding to the underlying implementation. Basically refactor to a Pimpl in order to get the syntax you want in the objects that you use in your interface.

Comment: I was simplifying my situation. It's not that it is always on the heap. It is that I am usually dealing with a reference which was passed around.

Answer (score 1):

It is often a good idea to wrap your heap allocation details in a regular type, and use the regular type rather than a pointer.

```
class EventHandler_Impl {
public:
        void Call(void* sender, EventArgs e);

        void operator() (void* sender, EventArg e){ Call(sender, e); }
};
```

then we write:

```
struct EventHandler {
  void operator()(void* sender, EventArg e){ (*pImpl)(sender, e); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<EventHandler_Impl> pImpl;
};
```

we have a "regular" type `EventHandler` that stores a pointer to the "actual" class.  It has methods that forward to the `pImpl`.

The state of this class is just one pointer.  It automatically deletes the `pImpl` when it goes out of scope.  The `std::unique_ptr` has the overhead of a pointer (which you'd store instead), except it destroys the `pImpl` object when it goes out of scope.

You can make it move-only, or manually implement a copy constructor (adding to the `_Impl` interface the ability to clone itself).

It is a bit of boilerplate.

You can do away with writing methods in the `_Impl` by simply writing them in the regular type, and having them access only state through the `pImpl` pointer if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `EventHandler*` is a pointer to a type, which is simply not callable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another functor as a wrapper, you'd only need to call it in a slightly different way.

```
struct EventHandlerCaller
{
   void operator() (EventHandler* eh, void* sender, EventArg& e)
   { 
     eh->operator()(nullptr, sender, e);
   }
}

static EventHandlerCaller caller;
EventHandler* EH;
caller(eh, nullptr, EventArgs::Empty());
```